# JavaScript program makes use of programs in other languages

Tags: javascript, java, c++, node.js, typescript

I have a javascript/typescript programs that need to make use of existing libraries written in Java, C and C++, python, etc.

What is the best way to facilitate the communication?

What I can think of is to implement each of them as different Web services on local computer. Is there other ways that can reduce overhead of communication, and reduce the effort making the communication possible (like wrapping them in services)?

Comment: Have a look at Edgejs (https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), that allows you to call into Python, C# & other languages from JavaScript (node.js environment). However it doesn't support Java, C and C++.

Comment: C/C++ are supported directly by developing plugins for v8/nodejs. See the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options to glue the different libraries together:

1. Bridge modules that let you call the libraries directly from Node:

   - [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java)
   - [node-python](https://github.com/electronifie/node-python)
   - [Edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) for c#
   - [NaN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) for C/C++
2. Message queue that will serve as the bus between the different applications like [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
3. Wrap each program/library as a web service (as you suggested)

Answer (score 1):

If your TypeScript script runs in NodeJs, then you can run an external process using Node's [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdio).

If your TypeScript script runs in a browser, then an HTTP request is the most easy way.